# Allow NestedScrollView to scroll completely inside a BottomSheet with a Custom Behaviour

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet, android-jetpack

I have a bottom sheet with a child NestedScrollView. I want to scroll the entire NestedScrollView all the way to bottom without sliding the bottom sheet to up side.

If user wants the bottom sheet to go all the way up they have to use the anchor no other way.

Now when use start scrolling down, after the entire content is scrolled i want the bottom sheet to hide on next scroll action.

As default bottom sheet behavior doesn't allow that  I have created my own custom behavior and overidden the onNestedScroll() and onNestedPreScroll().

There are two issue I am facing:

1 : The Nestedscrollview scrolls partially and stops because with respect to bottom sheet it sees there is no more content to scroll. I have to slide up the sheet in order to see the rest content. Means I cannot see the last item inside the NestedScrollView without expanding the sheet.

2: How can I detect whether the NestedScrollChild is scrolling up or scrolling down. Because I want the BottomSheet to intercept events once the scrollview finished scrolling its content. I tried onNestedPreScroll but seems like it is not necessarily triggered every time a child is being scroll. Is attaching a listener to scrollview is the only solution?

Link to see the issue in GIF 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/RPmDFEtR9TbGHrau6

Below is my layout and behavior class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

-->

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background_shaded"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="35dp"
        app:behavior_fitToContents="false"
        app:layout_behavior="com.pyus13.bottomsheetsample.MyBottomSheetBehaviour">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bottom_sheet_anchor_holder"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/anchor">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/change_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Title 1"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Title 2"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Page 3"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Page 4"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Page 5"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Title"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Behavior class:

```
class MyBottomSheetBehaviour<V : View> @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context? = null, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attrs) {

private var isScrollingDown = false


override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED || state == STATE_HALF_EXPANDED) {
        return false
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event)
}

override fun onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, directTargetChild: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int): Boolean {
    Log.d("Scroll", "OnNestedScroll EVent $child $target $axes $type")
    if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED || state == STATE_HALF_EXPANDED) {
        if (target.canScrollVertically(1) || target.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, axes, type)
}

override fun onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int) {
    isScrollingDown = dy > 0
    super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type)
}
```

}

I want a behavior like this if someone can help would really be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same issue, though, the layout was a bit different and the behavior was to not intercept nested scroll, at all. Since there's still no answer, I think  it's worth to share my experience here.

So, my layout was the following:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior=".view.FullNestedScrollBottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_min_height"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/anchorImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
        />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabTextColor="#b2ffffff"
            app:tabIconTint="@color/selector_status_tab"
            app:tabRippleColor="#42ffffff"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            >
            ...
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I ended up with the following approach:

1. Forbid the `BottomSheet` to accept nested scroll:

```
class FullNestedScrollBottomSheetBehavior<V: View>(
  context: Context,
  attrs: AttributeSet?
): BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attrs) {
  override fun onStartNestedScroll(...) = false
}
```

2. Dynamically change the height of the parent of the nested scroll element (in my case it's a `ViewPager` which holds `NestedScrollView` and `RecyclerView`) according to the real height of the `BottomSheet`'s visible part:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
  bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {}
    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
      val height = view.height - bottomSheet.top - anchorImage.height + 4.dp - tabLayout.height
      val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height)
      viewPager.layoutParams = params
    }
  })
}
```

3. Since the `onSlide()` will not be called until you drag your `BottomSheet`, the above logic should be duplicated to something like `onViewCreated()`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  view.post {
    val h = view.height - bottomSheetLayout.top - anchorImage.height + 4.dp - tabLayout.height
    val p = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, h)
    viewPager.layoutParams = p
  }
  // here goes the code from the second point
}
```

I think the provided solution may be a good tip to implement the exact behavior required in the question.